# Use of recursion in strings?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am a beginner in coding and I attended a placement assessment and I kept trying to arrive at a logic of this one question.Even after assessment I tried to refer and solve but then I couldn't.Some help would be appreciated...
I don't remember the constraints etc , but the question goes like.
They have given two strings "11100" and "1111000" as input.(They are first two strings)
Formula for third string goes as follows : 
No. of ones = 1 x no. of ones in second string + 2 x no. of zeros in first string.
 No. of zeros = 2 x no. of zeros in second string + 2 x no. of ones in first string.


Basically for nth number formula goes something like:

No. of ones in nth string = 1 x no. of ones in (n-1)th string + 2 x no. of zeros in (n-2)th string

No. of zeros = 2 x no. of zeros in second (n-1)th + 2 x no. of ones in (n-2)th  string.


So they'll give an number n and for that position we need to find the string.

Please help me, I have been struggling with this question for weeks....

**Answer in c++ would be appreciated since I have a good understanding in it.**

Comment: Hint: this is just the algorithm for generating Fibonacci numbers dressed up in fancy clothes.

Comment: What have you tried? Don't stress out on these types of problems, just try and solve them stupidly first.

Comment: I came up with an approach but didn't know how to make it work and approach further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone can suggest improvements to this at some point, but here is what I could quickly put together.

First observation: The actual strings don't matter. All we need to store are the number of zeros and the number of ones, which we can do in a POD struct.

Second observation: This looks a lot like a variation on the Fibonacci sequence and we can use a similar algorithm. Each nth string depends on the previous *two* strings. Therefore we need three strings to iterate over this sequence: the next one (here `n3`), the current one (here `n2`) and the previous one (here `n1`). `n3` can be computed exactly according to your formula. For the next iteration, we "cycle through" the strings, so that - again - `n2` becomes the current one and `n1` becomes the one before that.

Code in C++20:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

struct Occurences
{
    unsigned zeros;
    unsigned ones;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Occurences const &occ)
{
    out << '[' << occ.zeros << ", " << occ.ones << ']';
    return out;
}

void findNthOccurence(Occurences n1, Occurences n2, unsigned nMax)
{
    for (unsigned n = 3; n <= nMax; ++n)
    {
        Occurences n3{.zeros = 2 * n2.zeros + 2 * n1.ones,
                      .ones = n2.ones + 2 * n1.zeros};
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;

        std::cout << n << ": " << n2 << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string_view const str1{"11100"};
    std::string_view const str2{"1111000"};

    Occurences const n1{.zeros = static_cast<unsigned>(std::ranges::count(str1, '0')),
                        .ones = static_cast<unsigned>(str1.size()) - n1.zeros};
    Occurences const n2{.zeros = static_cast<unsigned>(std::ranges::count(str2, '0')),
                        .ones = static_cast<unsigned>(str2.size()) - n2.zeros};


    std::cout << "[zeros, ones]\n"
              << "1: " << n1 << "\n2: " << n2 << '\n';

    findNthOccurence(n1, n2, 10U);
}
```

Output:

```
[zeros, ones]
1: [2, 3]
2: [3, 4]
3: [12, 8]
4: [32, 14]
5: [80, 38]
6: [188, 102]
7: [452, 262]
8: [1108, 638]
9: [2740, 1542]
10: [6756, 3758]
```

Printing the actual resulting (long) string is trivial and is omitted here.

Lastly, note that while the formula is recursively defined, we do not actually need to implement it recursively.

Comment: Thanks loads @Yun ! This ofcourse helps me a tons and gave me an idea.... But these terms seem a little complex to me but i'll get through it....

Comment: @PerfectPlatinum You're welcome! What exactly seems a little complex?

Comment: I have never used the header string_view and it is not getting compiled in my ide and I am not sure what it does and also I have never used static cast and the 10U also I am not sure what exactly it's doing ....<unsigned> is it stl???

Comment: @PerfectPlatinum Perhaps you have an older compiler that doesn't support C++20's ranges? If so, replace it with the regular [count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). [String view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) was introduced in C++17, but replacing it with a `std::string` will work as well. `unsigned` is a just the `unsigned int` type. `10U` is the value `10` and of the type `unsigned int`. I can't fully explain everything in a comment here, so I suggest searching for these terms on SO or elsewhere. If it's not clear, then submit another question

Comment: I am sort of clear now and really found the above code very useful.... and helped me understand the concept whole lot better... Thank you once again...